# Pure-dimensional intersection of smooth varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a complex smooth projective variety of degree $d$ and dimension $m$, such that $X$ is not contained in any projective subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $P\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective space of dimension $n-m$. Then we know that if $P$ and $X$ intersect properly, $P\cap X$ is a zero-dimensional subscheme of length $d$.

I'm wondering if some similar properties hold for non-properly intersections. More precisely, I have the following questions.

Question: Suppose that $X$ and $P$ do not contain each other, and $\dim P\cap X= 1$. Assume that $n$ and $m$ are not too small (for example, take $n=9, m=6$).

1. Is the projective scheme $P\cap X$ pure-dimensional? I guess the answer is yes, but I don't know how to prove this yet...
2. How to compute the degree of $P\cap X$?
3. When is $P\cap X$ connected?

I think one of the possible methods is to describe $P\cap X$ as the zero locus of a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)^{\oplus m}$.

Answer (score 1):

No for 1. For instance, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be the Veronese surface, and let $P$ be the intersection of two hyperplanes that correspond to the conics
$$
C_1 = \{xy = 0\},
\qquad 
C_2 = \{xz = 0\}
$$
in $X \cong \mathbb{P}^2$. Then
$$
X \cap P = C_1 \cap C_2 = \{x = 0\} \cup \{y = z = 0\}
$$
is the union of a curve and a point.

Comment: Thanks for your example! How about 2.? Is it possible that $d$ is large but the degree of $P\cap X$ is much smaller than $d$?

Comment: What do you mean by the degree of a non-equidimensional scheme?